# Missing words in parshas zachor or parshas parah

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, four-parshiot

If someone didn't hear words (or perhaps even an entire verse) from Parshas Zachor or Parshas Parah, are they yotzee b'dieved? I'm specifically asking in this case since Parshas Zachor is d'oraisa and there are some who say Parshas Parah is also d'oraisa. However I suppose the question could apply as well to Parshas Shekalim or Parshas HaChodesh.

Comment: There __might__ be some who think Parshas Parah is d'oraisa. We've never actually found anyone who said that.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that someone who didn't hear something can fulfill the mitzva of hearing that thing?

Comment: The idea is the ikar

Comment: A parasha sheet I picked up at shul writes the following: "השומע פרשת זכור וחיסר כמה תיבות, כל ששמע עיקר ענין זכירת מעשה עמלק יצא ידי חובתו (הליכות שלמה)" If I had a copy of הליכות שלמה and could look it up in the primary source I would make this an answer.

Comment: @Eliyahu I have the sefer and will check, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

[The Rivevos Ephraim chelek 5:584:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1086&pgnum=458) writes that, since if one misses one word of krias megila they are not yotzei (Mishna Brurah 690:5), accordingly it seems that certainly by parshas zachor which is a Torah obligation if one misses one word he is not yotzei: like the Sefer Mikraei Kodesh siman 7 writes, it isn't any lower than megillah. Therefore one should be careful to listen to every single word.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow his logic. By Megillah the Mitzva is to read the whole book. By Zachor the goal is to remember Amalek. If the word missed doesn't affect the remembering it's very possible you still fulfill the Mitzva. At least it's not completely obvious otherwise.

Comment: I remember seeing such an idea,but I posted an answer which is at least a written source,will try to find the other tzad